# The vertical lines not completed in a table

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

The vertical line is not completing when I am trying to add a `new column` in the `table`. The corresponding code is attached here. It will be helpful if someone tries to modify this code and insert a `new column` without any problem. Because I have many such tables initially but now I am trying to insert a `new column`. The `output` is. [image]

```
\begin{table}[!htb]
\begin{center}
\caption{Tablemy} 
\label{tab:tab5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Selection criteria} &  \multirow{3}{*}{Data} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{MC } &\multirow{3}{*}{eff}  & new\\
\cline{3-7}
&& a & b & c & d &  e &\\
\hline
A  & 17 &0.52 & 0.78 & 0.41& 0.26 & 0&  7.55$\%$ & \\
B  & 14& 0.52 &0.78 &0.41 & 0.26&0 & 7.54$\%$ &\\
C  & 14 & 0.52 & 0.78 &0.41 & 0.26 & 0& 7.47$\%$ & \\

D & 6  & 0.52 & 0.78 &0.41 &0.26 & 0& 7.35$\%$ & \\

E &4 &0.52 &0.78 & 0.41 & 0.26 & 0&  7.35$\%$ & \\


\hline 

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You problem (not explainded in the accepted answer) was: you forot one `&` in the line `a b c ... e`. More precisely, you wrote `e &\\ ` but correct is `e &&\\ ` because you have two next columns after `e`, no only one. The second row of your table was closed in the 8-th column but you have 9 columns.

Comment: Yes!! Thank You! I got my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `multirow` for such tabular.

Many people would recommand not to use vertical rules and to use `booktabs`. That's why I propose a version with `booktabs`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}} 
\toprule
Selection & Data & \multicolumn{5}{c}{MC} & eff& new \\
\cline{3-7}
critera & & a & b & c & d & e & & \\ 
\midrule
A & 17 &0.52 & 0.78 & 0.41& 0.26 & 0& 7.55$\%$ & \\ 
B & 14& 0.52 &0.78 &0.41 & 0.26&0 & 7.54$\%$ &\\ 
C & 14 & 0.52 & 0.78 &0.41 & 0.26 & 0& 7.47$\%$ & \\
D & 6 & 0.52 & 0.78 &0.41 &0.26 & 0& 7.35$\%$ & \\
E &4 &0.52 &0.78 & 0.41 & 0.26 & 0& 7.35$\%$ & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{c|}} 
\hline
Selection & Data & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{MC} & eff& new \\
\cline{3-7}
critera & & a & b & c & d & e & & \\ 
\hline
A & 17 &0.52 & 0.78 & 0.41& 0.26 & 0& 7.55$\%$ & \\ 
B & 14& 0.52 &0.78 &0.41 & 0.26&0 & 7.54$\%$ &\\ 
C & 14 & 0.52 & 0.78 &0.41 & 0.26 & 0& 7.47$\%$ & \\
D & 6 & 0.52 & 0.78 &0.41 &0.26 & 0& 7.35$\%$ & \\
E &4 &0.52 &0.78 & 0.41 & 0.26 & 0& 7.35$\%$ & \\
\hline
\end{tabular} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Thank You, for the quick response!! This works great!!